# Integrate discord webhooks with mongodb alerts

Tags: mongodb, discord, webhooks, mongodb-atlas

I am using mondoDB atlas alerts and I am trying to set up alerts to use the discord webhooks. I have an email section set up on the same alert and those are being sent so I know it is triggering. However the webhook doesnt fire in discord. I have tested the webhook as well and I can get it to fire its just in mongo it never runs. Any guidance will be appreciated.

[image]